# Is Mahalanobis distance dependent from the vector dimensions?

Tags: distributions, distance-functions, model-comparison

I would like to know if Mahalanobis distance is a normalized measure and the feature dimensions (or vector dimensions) do not affect the measure?

In other words if I have a vector $ v \in \Re^n $ with an associated Mahalanobis distance $ D_v $ and a vector $ x \in \Re^m $ where $ m >> n$ and with a distance $ D_x$ associated, could I directly compare $ D_v $ with $ D_x$ value or there is a dimension effect?

If is there a dimension effect how it is possible to compensate for it?

Thank you.

Comment: the answer hinges crucially on whether or not the mean vector and covariance matrix used to compute the MD have been estimated from the data on which the MD's are computed.

Comment: In my case I have a training set on which I estimate mean and covariance.

Comment: Mahalanobis distance is dimensionless in the sense that it doesn't matter what units you measure in, it will be unchanged. But if you want to compare measures across things with *different numbers of dimensions*, that's quite different - you'd divide by the number of dimensions, but I really have no sense that this is going to be very meaningful in most situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any subset of observation $H$ and denoting

$$(t,S)=\left(\text{ave}_{i\in H}x_i,\text{cov}_{i\in H}x_i\right)$$

then

$$\sum_{i\in H}\;\;\;(x_i-t)'S^{-1}(x_i-t)=p(n-1)$$

where $p$ is the rank of $S$ and $n=\#H$. So when 
 $(t,S)$ have been estimated on the same sample on 
which the MD's are computed the answer to your first 
question is 'no'. The answer to your second question 
is 'yes'. Finally, the answer to your third question is 
'by dividing the MD's by the square root of the right 
hand side of the equation above'.

Comment: Probably my comment was incomplete (and also my question).
I have a training set with examples all $ \in \Re^n $ and then I compute $ D_x $, I have another training set with examples $ \in \Re^m $ then I compute $ D_v $.
I would like to know if $ D_x $ and $ D_v $ are comparable or there is a way to compare them.

Comment: yes, your question is incomplete and so is your comment above. And you keep alluding the most important element: call $H_x$ your first training set. Do the observations used to compute $(t_x,S_x)$ used to compute $D_x$ belong to $H_x$? Same for $H_y$ (the second training set) and $D_y$.

Comment: I'm sorry... Yes!

Comment: than my answer above fully answers your questions: 'no you cannot directly compare $D_x$ to $D_y$', 'yes, because there is a dimension effect' and 'to make $D_x$ and $D_y$ comparable simply divide them by $\sqrt{p_x(n_x−1)}$ and $\sqrt{p_y(n_y−1)}$ respectively, where $p_x$ ($p_y$) is the length of $x$ ($y$) and $n_x$ ($n_y$) the number of elements in $H_x$ ($H_y$).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.
I found (probably) another two-step method to compare distances: basically since we know that (in some cases) $D^2$ distributes as a $\chi^2$ with $n$ and $m$ dof, we build a $\chi_x^{2}$ and a $\chi_y^{2}$ and then we compare the p-value associated with distances $D_x^2$ and $D_y^2$.

Comment: weal, by doing this you are not controlling for the size of the subsets ($n_y$ and $n_x$).

Comment: Well in my case $n_x$ and $n_y$ are equivalent, so the only thing that varies is the dimension of $x$ and $y$.